# How do I stop the graph from changing when I add labels to a geom_bar?

Tags: r, geom-bar, geom-text

[image]

When I add the label for each bar with *geom_text* the whole graph changes.

```
 ggplot(Ch2_Species_TreeMeasure, mapping=aes(x=BarkGroups, fill= factor(StemLiv1)))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill")+facet_grid(cols = vars(Species))+ 
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..), stat = "count")
```

[image]

How can I add the number of observations to each bar without changing the graph?

Comment: Hi Isaac. If you look at the y axis of your two different plots you will se the problem. Your bars are proportions so they scale to 1, but your text labels are plotted at the value of the raw counts. This means if you plot them both together, the bars will be compressed down to the bottom of the y axis. You need to choose counts _or_ proportions - not both

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron. Solved the problem with  this code:  geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat="count", position = position_fill(vjust=0.5))